# Equivalent of Matlab's "randsample" random sample

Tags: java, matlab, random

Is there a function in Java like the `randsample` in Matlab which can return weighted samples(sampled uniformly at random with replacement, and having a weight- `w[i]` for each number. The probability that a number i is selected is w(i)/sum(w).)?

I want to use something like this

```
    randsample([0 1],1,true,[0.2 0.8]);
```

Comment: I dont know if there is something already. But it should be easy to write one.  Can you tell us more clearly what the parameters `[0 1], 1, true and [p1 p2]` represent?

Comment: Are you asking for weighted average for a an array of numbers? Like if you want to compute a weighted average for weights/lengths?
So something like this: (sum (weight * length))/ (sum (length))?

Comment: Yes, I want to compute weighted average, i.e. probability that a number i is selected for an entry of  output y[i] in y = randsample(...,true,w) is w(i)/sum(w). for eg if the default example in matlab                     is    R = randsample('ACGT',48,true,[0.15 0.35 0.35 0.15])  and it    returns R =

TCGCTGCAGCGGTGCCTTCTACGAACCGCCAGCTCCGGCGGAGCGGGC

Comment: the 'true' is for sampling with replacement, default is 'false' which means sampling without replacement

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/random.html) library. Specifically, it looks like you're interested in the [Binomial Distribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/index.html).

Hope that helps!