# Random Selection From Multiset

Tags: java, optimization, multiset

I have a hashmap with string to integer mappings, and I'm trying to select a random entry from it, weighted on the integer associated with each. The code I'm currently using generates the cumulative sums for all the entries. However, this is *incredibly* slow and inefficient when you need to do such and operation many times. Any ideas as to how I should do this?

My code, which is in terrible need of optimization:

```
public String getRandom(Random rnd) {

    ArrayList<Entry<String, MutableInteger>> entries = new ArrayList<>(results.entrySet());

    ArrayList<Long> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    long cumulative = -1;

    for(Entry<String, MutableInteger> e : entries) {
        ints.add(cumulative += e.getValue().get());
        vals.add(e.getKey());
    }

    long l = Math.abs(rnd.nextLong()) % (cumulative == 0 ? 1 : cumulative);
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(ints, l);
    index = (index >= 0) ? index : -index-1;

    return vals.get(index);
}
```

Comment: First thing: why calculate the cum-sum each time you are sampling. Do it once and maybe after modifying your data (maybe an class abstracting this would be a good idea; always keeps valid data-structures for sampling ready). Second thing: If the sampling-method is too slow, use something more advanced like the **alias-method**.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863638/weighted-sampling-with-replacement-in-java